# PHP if not greater than 1, print text

Tags: php, mysql, printing, echo

In my code which can be found below, I have the server checking if the person is on a team. If they are, it displays something, if they aren't it displays something different. It works if the person is on a team (it prints the correct thing), but it doesn't show anything if the person is not on a team. Any help?

```
            if($_SESSION["username"]){
                $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE game='bl2' AND players LIKE '%$sessiongamt%'") or die("Could not allocate information!");
                $num1 = 0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
                  $num = ++$num;
                  $amount = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
                  $id = $row["id"];
                  $name = $row["name"];
                  $link = $row["link"];

                  if($amount < 0 || $num1 < 0){
                    print '<hr/>
                      <img src="../../img/games/black-ops-2-img.png" />
                      <h2>Black Ops 2: XBOX360</h2>
                      <hr/>
                        <div class="btn-group" style="margin-left: 210px;">
                          <a href="../findamatch.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Find a Match</a>
                          <a href="../reportamatch.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Report a Match</a>
                          <a href="../matchissue.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Match Issue</a>
                          <a href="../support.php?id=bl2" class="btn">Support</a>
                        </div>
                      <hr/>
                      <h2>Featured Teams</h2><hr/>';
                  }else{
                    print '<hr/>
                      <img src="../../img/games/black-ops-2-img.png" />
                      <h2>Black Ops 2: XBOX360</h2>
                      <hr/>
                        <div class="btn-group" style="margin-left: 210px;">
                          <a href="../findamatch.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Find a Match</a>
                          <a href="../reportamatch.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Report a Match</a>
                          <a href="../matchissue.php?g=bl2" class="btn">Match Issue</a>
                          <a href="../support.php?id=bl2" class="btn">Support</a>
                        </div>
                      <hr/>
                      <h2>Featured Teams</h2><hr/>';
                  }
              }
            }
```

Comment: Putting code in links is discouraged (since it will make your question impossible to understand for future users if the link stops working), especially for such a large amount of code (much of which is irrelevant to your question- especially the HTML and CSS). Could you extract the code that is relevant and post just that?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're outputting anything in the if block that checks if the person is on a team. Just assigning a value.

Comment: @DavidRobinson The op is updated.

Comment: @Robbert How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: you need to examine your IF logic inside your loop. You set $num1 to 0 before the while, then never change it, so it can never be less then 0. you keep refilling $amount with the number of rows returned INSIDE the loop (to which that number will never change), which that line would only get to that line by having at least 1 row to enter the while loop, so amount will always be >= 1, so $amount will NEVER be less than 0. Your top block will never be hit

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple check like this

```
if(isset($players) && $players < 1){
  $team = "You are not a team";
}else{
.. 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try an echo statement to see what is the value of players and if it's coming up correctly?

Comment: That helped me out a lot. I never thought of that. Thanks.